# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC website which has a page that downloads a power point file created by Interop.PowePoint.dll. When I deploy a release of the website to my own machine in IIS, the download stops working and give the error from the description.

Here is my code:

```
          MessageFilter.Register();
        // This registers the IOleMessageFilter to handle any threading 
        // errors.

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        //creating powerpoint aaplication
        Application powerPointApplication = new Application();
        //powerPointApplication.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;

        var pptPresentation = powerPointApplication.Presentations.Add(MsoTriState.msoFalse);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout =
            pptPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];

        //Step5.Insert a slide by calling the Add method on the Presentation.Slides collection, and add some texts to the slide.

        var index = 1;

        var oSlides = pptPresentation.Slides;

        if (model.Configuration.Ratio == "4:3")
        {
            pptPresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = PpSlideSizeType.ppSlideSizeOnScreen;
        }

        foreach (var slide in model.Slides)
        {
            var oSlide = oSlides.AddSlide(index, customLayout);

            oSlide.FollowMasterBackground = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
            //oSlide.Background.Fill.BackColor.RGB = Convert.ToInt32(ExtractHex(model.Configuration.Background), 16);
            oSlide.Background.Fill.BackColor.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(HexToColor(model.Configuration.Background));

            //content
            var oShape = oSlide.Shapes[2];

            //oShape.LockAspectRatio = MsoTriState.msoTriStateToggle;

            var oTxtFrame = oShape.TextFrame;
            var oTxtRange = oTxtFrame.TextRange;
            oTxtRange.Text = FormatText(slide);
            //oTxtRange.Font.Size = model.Configuration.FontSize;

            oTxtRange.Font.Color.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(HexToColor(model.Configuration.Forecolor));

            oTxtRange.Font.Size = GetFontSize(slide);

            if (model.Configuration.Font != null)
            {
                oTxtRange.Font.Name = model.Configuration.Font;
            }
            //oTxtRange.Font.Bold = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
            oShape.TextEffect.Alignment = MsoTextEffectAlignment.msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered;


            oTxtFrame.HorizontalAnchor = MsoHorizontalAnchor.msoAnchorCenter;
            //oTxtFrame.VerticalAnchor = MsoVerticalAnchor.msoAnchorMiddle;

            var format = oTxtRange.Paragraphs().ParagraphFormat;
            format.Bullet.Type = PpBulletType.ppBulletNone;

            //format.Alignment = PpParagraphAlignment.ppAlignCenter;

            index++;
        }

        //Step6.Save the presentation as a pptx file and close it.
        model.Name = "Praiser.ppt";
        string fileFullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + model.Name;

        pptPresentation.SaveAs(fileFullPath, PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation, MsoTriState.msoTriStateMixed);
        pptPresentation.Close();

        powerPointApplication.Quit();

        MessageFilter.Revoke();

        return File(fileFullPath, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", model.Name);
```

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but do you actually have PowerPoint installed on the computer where you're encountering this error?  Interop.Poweroint.dll is a kind of bridge between your app and Powerpoint.  If there's no PowerPoint at the other end of the bridge, you're in for a bath.

Comment: Yes! I do have It installed. Debugging the application everything works fine but when I release to IIS the error happens.

Comment: OK, sometimes that's not obvious to everybody. I'm not a server-guy so can't be of much help here.  Sorry.